# Java: Sorting a List<Map<String, Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(dataMap.values())

Tags: java

**I would like to ask how to sort this list of Map by it's values which is the Object itself**

This is a code from my **ServiceImpl**:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> dataList = serviceRequestDataDao.findServiceRequestData(serviceRequestQuery);
```

...

```
 Map<Long, Map<String, Object>> dataMap = toMap(dataList,customReportSetting.getReportType());
```

...

```
dataList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>(dataMap.values());
```

The **dataMap.values()** are all the values that I have retrieved from the database. I tried to display it using this code since I want it to be sorted by **Creation Date Value** (from *oldest to latest*):

```
for (Map<String, Object> mapList : dataList){
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : mapList.entrySet()){
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();

        if (key.equals("Creation Date")){
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }       
}
```

I just don't know how to sort the  **WHOLE** list containing **map of string (keys)** and **objects (values)**.

The **output of Creation Date** is like this:

```
05/17/2016 02:56:40 PM
```

Comment: What is the type of the creation date? `java.sql.Timestamp`?

Comment: use `Collections.sort(dataList, new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {...}`

Comment: The creation date is a datetime2 type.

Comment: Hint for titles: keep clutter out of them (and ideally out of the body as well), i.e. `dataList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(dataMap.values())` is totally superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort a `List` of objects that don't have a natural order (`Map` doesn't), you call [`Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).

Assuming your `Creation Date` value is a `java.sql.Timestamp`, this is how:

```
Collections.sort(dataList, new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, Object> row1, Map<String, Object> row2) {
        Timestamp createDate1 = (Timestamp) row1.get("Creation Date");
        Timestamp createDate2 = (Timestamp) row2.get("Creation Date");
        return createDate1.compareTo(createDate2);
    }
});
```

Or this shorter lambda version if you're on Java 8+:

```
Collections.sort(dataList, (row1, row2) -> {
    Timestamp createDate1 = (Timestamp) row1.get("Creation Date");
    Timestamp createDate2 = (Timestamp) row2.get("Creation Date");
    return createDate1.compareTo(createDate2);
});
```

Which of course can be shortened to one of these two (second taken from [answer by @shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38966096/5221149)):

```
Collections.sort(dataList, (r1,r2) -> ((Timestamp)r1.get("Creation Date")).compareTo((Timestamp)r2.get("Creation Date")));

dataList.sort(Comparator.comparing(r -> (Timestamp)r.get("Creation Date")));
```

---

**UPDATE**

To add a secondary sort by `Resolved Date`, you'd first have to decide how `null` values sort. That was not a consideration for `Creation Date`, since that is a `NOT NULL` column, but `Resolved Date` is likely null capable. Let's sort `null` values *last*.

For pre-Java 8, do this:

```
Timestamp date1 = (Timestamp) row1.get("Creation Date");
Timestamp date2 = (Timestamp) row2.get("Creation Date");
int cmp = date1.compareTo(date2);
if (cmp == 0) {
    date1 = (Timestamp) row1.get("Resolved Date");
    date2 = (Timestamp) row2.get("Resolved Date");
    cmp = (date1 == null ? (date2 == null ? 0 : 1)
                         : (date2 == null ? -1 : date1.compareTo(date2)));
}
return cmp;
```

To sort `null` values first, swap `1` and `-1`.

For Java 8, do this:

```
dataList.sort(Comparator.comparing((Map<String, Object> r) -> (Timestamp)r.get("Creation Date"))
                        .thenComparing(r -> (Timestamp)r.get("Resolved Date"),
                                       Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

With method chaining, the compiler was unable to infer the type of the `r` parameter, so it has to be explicitly given on the first lambda.

Comment: The creation date from the mssql database is a datetime2 type.

Comment: Hi @Andreas. The type from the mssql server is a datetime2. I tried "String" instead of the "Timestamp" because it gives me infinite loading. I wasn't sure about the type of the creation date after being stored in map because there was another programmer who did it. But thanks to you, I had it working already. I think? It worked. Do you think it really worked? Hahaha

Comment: @monsteruniversity0908 if your using String to sort, don't. String's `compareTo` is completely different from Timestamp's

Answer (score 2):

Going with @Andreas's assumption that `Creation Date` is a `Timestamp`:

```
dataList.sort(Comparator.comparing(m -> (Timestamp)m.get("Creation Date")));
```

Comment: Dang, I keep forgetting `Comparator.comparing()`. I added it to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38966044/5221149) for completeness. Makes the secondary sort OP asked for very simple too.

Answer (score 0):

If I talk about list object which is given by you :

```
List<Map<String, Object>> dataList = serviceRequestDataDao.findServiceRequestData(serviceRequestQuery);
```

We can sort it by using Java 8 feature stream API :

```
dataList= dataList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(map -> (Timestamp)map.get("Creation Date"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```